# How do I add five minutes to a timestamp in Golang?

Tags: docker, go, timestamp

I am wondering how to add time to a timestamp. The intention is to be able to get the current timestamp, add five minutes to it, then show the new one. I am trying to stop the output after five minutes then stop the docker container. I am doing this because I am running a process that never stops in the container and I want it to stop after five minutes of running.

```
out, err := cli.ContainerLogs(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerLogsOptions{ShowStdout: true, ShowStderr: true, Follow: true, Until: /* Code Here */})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)

if err := cli.ContainerStop(ctx, resp.ID, nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: You could use a ticker, start the ticker in a gorountine above everything. Set the ticker to tick every 5 minutes. On the first tick. Os.Exit(0), https://gobyexample.com/tickers.
That should allow you to stop the long running process in 5 minutes

Comment: @reticentroot Can you give me an example?

Comment: check out the Go example link above on how to use tickers.  The example has the gist on how to start one. Mod it to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another example of how to use a Timer in Go. You could spin up your timer. Set it `time.Minute * 5` then run your long running process.  When the timer ticks send the quit signal to exit the program. It's important to use os.Exit() vs return as return will exit the gorountine not the program.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second)
    go func() {
        <-timer.C
        fmt.Println("Quiting")
        os.Exit(0)
    }()

    // long running proccess
    for {

    }

}
```